# vk api авторизация

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

При попытке отправки запроса на code в ответе нет заголовка "location".
Находил рекомендацию отключить следование редиректу. Отключил. Тоже самое.
Что делать?

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?" +
                "client_id=" + clientId +
                "&client_secret=" + clientSecret +
                "&scope=" + scope +
                "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri +
                "&display=page" +
                "&v=5.67" +
                "&response_type=code");
HttpResponse response;
response = httpClient.execute(post);
```